# Using @RequestBody with wrapper object

Tags: spring

I'm using `entity - repository - service - controller` architecture. In the controller I would like to get an object not represented by the entity layer. I did some research and I have found two solutions.

1. Use a Map<String, Object>
2. Use a wrapper class.

My questions are:

1. In the second scenario, where should I put the wrapper class? Is it a new entity or I should have a separate folder for wrapper classes?
2. What's the difference between having a DTO and the second approach?

Answer (score 1):

Ans 1. It is not an Entity at all, it's just a Response wrapper DTO. I would recommend having 2 packages **dto* and **entity*. The classes which are exposed from APIs should go inside **dto* and those representing entities should be in the **entity*. You can further divide **dto* to **dto/request* and **dto/response*.
Ans 2. I don't see any difference. It's always good practice to wrap any collection in a Response DTO to have room for Metadata like Pagination.